# Como puedo mostrar el nombre de un campo en la tabla, seleccionando un elemento del combobox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un combobox el cual si almacena el id  pero quiero que en la tabla de SQL me muestre el nombre en lugar del id en el campo.

este es el método de mi cobobox

```
public void CargarSexos()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conexiondb = conexionDB.ConectarDB())
        {
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_CargarSexo", conexiondb);
            data.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             data.Fill(ds3,"sexo");
            cbSex.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            cbSex.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbSex.DisplayMember = "sexo";

        }  
    }
```

esta es la tabla en SQL, sexo tiene referencia de otra tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi Store Procedure:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la tabla quiero que en Sexo me muestre "M" o "F" en vez de "1" o "2"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como tenes tu store procedure? No entiendo bien donde queres mostrar el nombre en lugar del ID. porque haces referencia a mostrarlo en tu sql y no tu combobox.

Comment: En mi tabla de sql quiero que en ven de que muestre el Id muestre el nombre de ese id que se ingreso